# How to represent uniqueness?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write an agent for determining what card a player has, and I am struggling to represent that each card can only have been dealt to a single player.

So have I have something^ like this:

```
player(p1).
player(p2).

card(ace).
card(king).
card(queen).
card(jack).
```

but I am struggling on writing the rule for uniqueness. Borrowing something from logic class, I though about defining uniqueness as "if X has Y, then if something has Y, that something must be X".

```
has_card(P, C) :-
    player(P),
    card(C),
    not(player(P2),
        P2 =\= P,
        has_card(P2, C)
    ).
```

but this fails because `not/3` is not defined.

I tried rewriting it as:

```
has_card(P, C) :-
    player(P),
    card(C),
    player(P2),
    P2 =\= P,
    not(has_card(P2,C)).
```

but then the query (which I expect to return `false`)

```
has_card(P, ace).
```

errors out with

```
ERROR: =\=/2: Arithmetic: `player1/0' is not a function
```

So, how can I represent uniqueness?

^ complicating --likely-- unnecessary details omitted

---

**EDIT:** in first attempt at `has_card` I have `P2==P` which should have been `P2=\=P`, fixed now

Comment: `p1` in my actual code is `player1`, that is probably it then, would the rewrite you suggest do what I intend it to?

Comment: **PS** fixed the code had `==` instead of `=/=` but that wouldn't have effected the compile error

Answer (score 2):

First off, as the error is telling you, you are using `=\=`, which is [arithmetic inequality](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arithpreds). For comparing on [standard order of terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compare), you should use `\==`.

Then, the "not" as in "true when negated goal not true", you should probably use `\+`, like this:

```
\+ a == b
```

which is the same as

```
a \== b
```

The `not/1` predicate is still available in most Prolog implementations but not recommended.

Fixing these two things will sort out the problem you are having at the moment.

But, as it is at the moment, your `has_card/2` at no point maps a card to a player, really (it uses circular logic as far as I can see). Since you are not showing how exactly you know which cards belong to which player at any given moment, it is difficult to comment on that. Either way, some sort of term that you pass around would be probably better than changing the database with `assert` and `retract`.